# Is it possible to reduce the width of headerFragment in leanback android tv app

Tags: android, android-tv

> I am trying to reduce the header Fragment width. But I am able to
>   change the text and icon inside the header Fragment not width.
>
> I have tried to set the width inside item layout but unfortunately it
>   doesn't work.
>
> icon_header_item.xml
>
> ```
> <RelativeLayout
>     android:layout_width="100dp"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content">
>
> <ImageView
>     android:id="@+id/header_icon"
>     android:layout_width="48dp"
>     android:layout_height="48dp"
>     android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>
>
> <TextView
>     android:id="@+id/header_label"
>     android:layout_width="140dp"
>     android:layout_below="@id/header_icon"
>     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
>
> </RelativeLayout> </android.support.v17.leanback.widget.NonOverlappingLinearLayout>
> ```
>
> see in the pic

[image]

Answer (score 11):

You can override the original dimensions in your `res/values/dimens.xml`

```xml
<dimen name="lb_browse_headers_width">210dp</dimen><!--  Original: 270  -->
<dimen name="lb_browse_rows_margin_start">178dp</dimen><!--  Original: 238  -->
```

Comment: That's worked perfectly but the **RowsFragment** end spacing is increased.